# How to mutate with dplyr based on the mean of a column and grouping variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the below example data and I am trying to create a new column with `mutate()` that takes each `dist` value and subtracts it from the mean of the entire `dist` column. To take it one step further, I would like the mean to be based on the `qtr` variable. For example, each `dist` value that corresponds to `qtr == 1` is subtracted from the mean of `dist` for `qtr == 1` only and so on. Hope that makes sense.

```
library(tidyverse)   

set.seed(10)
rd <- rep(rep(c(1:20), each = 4))
qtr <- rep(c(1:4), times = 20)
dist <- round(rnorm(n = 80, mean = 3000, sd = 500))
df <- data.frame(rd, qtr, dist)
```

I can get to here, but I'm not sure how I can account for the `qtr` variable. At the moment, the below code is taking the mean of `dist` irrespective of the value for `qtr`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(new_column = (dist - mean(dist)))
```

Comment: Use the `.by` argument. `dat %>% mutate(new_column = (dist - mean(dist)), .by = qtr)` (or the alternative `group_by()` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, @RitchieSacramento, but that syntax just creates another column called .by. Can you explain further, please?

Comment: You need to update `dplyr` - the `.by` feature was introduced in `v 1.1.0`.